# What libraries/modules could affect array's operation speed?

Tags: php, linux, arrays, performance

I got a strange behavior on 2 similar machines, both running ubuntu 10.04 amd64.

Consider this code:

```
<?php
$array = array('a', 'b');
for($i = 0; $i < 400000; $i++)
{
    is_array($array);
}
```

The same code perform in about 0,38 seconds on a machine, and about 4,13 in the other... the strange thing is that the faster pc has many few resources (cpu, ram) than the slower one, and only the array-related function seem to be affected.

In both machines PHP is at the same version, with fpm (pools and application code is updated via svn, so all the configuration is identical, except maybe for php5-* modules installed).

What can i check on the lowest machine to see if there something wrong?

Comment: Any php accelator maybe. did you check phpinfo() ? what are differences ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is xdebug installed / enabled? I know it slow down a lot PHP execution

Comment: i have xdebug in local , i checked and took 0.5 sec

Comment: Yes, it was xdebug. I tryed to disable stacktraces, but it was still slow - now i completely disabled xdebug and the same script run in about 0.2 seconds!